# Combine my two SQL Server queries into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I combine two queries? I am new to database. Both are working fine but combine both queries into a single query:

i need only one row with min value each column.. i used cast for two decimal needed.

```
SELECT
    Date_Time, 
    CAST(Column1 AS decimal(10, 2)) AS Column1,
    CAST(Column2 AS decimal(10, 2)) AS Column2,
    STATUS 
FROM Table

SELECT
    MIN(Column1) AS Column1,
    MIN(Column2) AS Column2 
FROM Table
```

Comment: Why do you want to combine it? The first query returns multiple rows as results but the second returns only a single row. Are you saying that you want to get the minimum of column1 for each date?

Comment: Yes i need only one row...  with min value and cast(Column) for decimal...

Comment: Your new query needs to be a single row with the minimum of each column after casting them to decimal? Do you need the `Date_Time` and `STATUS` columns?

Comment: Yes @charlieface

Comment: Please be clearer: yes to the first question, the second question or yes to both? If you need the other two columns, how do you want to aggregate them? With `MIN` also?

Comment: need min value of both column with cast so it will return only one row

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Windows Functions`:

```
   Select Date_Time,
 CAST(Column1 as decimal(10,2)) As Column1,
 CAST(Column2 as decimal(10,2)) As Column2 ,
 STATUS,
 Min(Column1 ) Over() as MinCol1,
 Min(Column2) Over() as MinCol2
  From Table
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the minimum value for each date then you need to use `group by` clause

```sql
SELECT
    Date_Time,
    MIN(Column1) as column1,
    MIN(Column2) as column2,
    MIN(CAST(Column1 AS decimal(10, 2))) AS decimal_Column1,
    MIN(CAST(Column2 AS decimal(10, 2))) AS decimal_Column2
FROM Table
GROUP BY Date_Time
```

Comment: i need one row with min value each column and cast(cast for decimal )

Comment: @CricNewsForFans I have updated the answer, is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your comments, it seems like you just need this:

```sql
SELECT
    MIN(CAST(Column1 AS decimal(10, 2))) AS decimal_Column1,
    MIN(CAST(Column2 AS decimal(10, 2))) AS decimal_Column2
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use window function to have all the rows from your first query along with two columns having minimum value for column1 and column 2 for each date_time and status.

```
SELECT
    Date_Time, 
    CAST(Column1 AS decimal(10, 2)) AS Column1,
    CAST(Column2 AS decimal(10, 2)) AS Column2,
    STATUS ,
    MIN(Column1)over(partition by date_time,status) AS MinColumn1,
    MIN(Column2)over(partition by date_time,status) AS MinColumn2

FROM Table
```

It would be better if you share sample input and output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the minimum values as separate columns, you would just use window functions:

```
SELECT Date_Time, 
       CAST(Column1 AS decimal(10, 2)) AS Column1,
       CAST(Column2 AS decimal(10, 2)) AS Column2,
       STATUS ,
       MIN(Column1) OVER () as min_column1,
       MIN(Column2) OVER () as min_column2
FROM Table;
```

If you want the minimum values as an additional row, you would use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT Date_Time, 
       CAST(Column1 AS decimal(10, 2)) AS Column1,
       CAST(Column2 AS decimal(10, 2)) AS Column2,
       STATUS 
FROM Table
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,
       MIN(Column1) AS Column1,
       MIN(Column2) AS Column2,
       NULL
FROM Table;
```